# Wilcoxon signed-rank test vs Mann Whitney U Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

## **Background**

Qualitative measurements are taken of a subject before and after some external stimuli

## **Aim**

Determine if measurements taken before and after stimuli are different (p<0.05)

## **Question**

1.) As the data is ordinal the medians should be compared? 
2.) As the subjects are used in both data sets the data is paired? 
3.) As the data is paired the Wilcoxon signed-rank test should be used over the Mann-Whitney U test as the former is for paired data?

**Thanks!!**

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What are the "qualitative measurements"? You say they are ordinal; it sounds like you already know the answer.

Comment: This looks like an assignment to me.

Comment: I think like many others you, or whoever set this, is being misled by a poor choice of function name in R. You are talking about a test due to WIlcoxon, not Wilcox. (Bizarrely, he did have a coauthor WIlcox.)

Comment: Removed the tag R. You may be using R, but the question does not depend on any software.

Comment: The Mann-Whitney U test, essentially equivalent to the Wilcoxon rank sum test, is a test to compare two _independent_ samples, not for paired data.

Answer (score 1):

You have paired (Before and After) data on $n$ subjects.
Specifically, suppose the data are Likert-5 responses
(1=strongly opposed, ..., 5=strongly favor), and you
expect After scores to be higher than Before scores. (Thus suppose we are looking at one-sided alternatives.)

A paired Wilcoxon signed-rank test is essentially
a (one-sample) Wilcoxon signed-rank test on the differences
'After - Before'. For specificity, differences
might span integers $-2, -1, 0, 1, 2.$

In many implementations, of the Wilcoxon signed-rank test,
including `wilcox.test` in R, there are really two
situations depending on whether the number $n$ of subjects
is 'small', say $n = 50,$ or 'large', say $n = 150.$

**Small sample.** Suppose you have $n = 50$ differences in vector `d` (fictitious data),
tabled as follows [using R]:

```
table(d)
d
-2 -1  0  1  2 
 5  9 16 13  7
```

Then a **Wilcoxon signed-rank test** gives a P-value of
questionable accuracy because of ties and zeros, but
certainly not a P-value that would cause us to reject
the null hypothesis that there is no difference between
Before and After. [The parameter `alt="greater"` of the procedure `wilcox.test` specifies a one-sided alternative.]

```
wilcox.test(d, alt="greater")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  d
V = 349, p-value = 0.1823
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location is greater than 0

Warning messages:
 1: In wilcox.test.default(d, alt = "greater") :
    cannot compute exact p-value with ties
2: In wilcox.test.default(d, alt = "greater") :
   cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

We might try a **sign test** of zero median, which looks
at the number of positive differences among non-zero
differences. This test can be done in R as follows:

```
sum(d != 0); sum(d > 0)
[1] 34   # non-zero
[1] 20   # positive

binom.test(20, 34, alt="greater")

        Exact binomial test

data:  20 and 34
number of successes = 20, number of trials = 34, 
 p-value = 0.1958
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.4332148 1.0000000
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
              0.5882353
```

Where the (clearly non-significant) P-value can also be found as:

```
1 - pbinom(19, 35, .5)
[1] 0.1957642
```

The sign test is generally less powerful than the Wilcoxon
signed rank test, but in this example it has the virtue
of giving an unequivocal P-value---even if not one leading
to rejection.

**Larger sample.^^ By contrast, let's look at a larger fictitious dataset `dd` from $n = 150$ 'subjects'.

```
table(dd)
dd
-2 -1  0  1  2 
18 19 38 43 32
```

Again here, there are many ties and zeros, but a
reasonably reliable P-value is approximated from the larger sample. For the larger sample, a **Wilcoxon signed rank test** gives strong
evidence against the null hypothesis, in favor of
increasing Likert scores.

```
wilcox.test(dd, alt="greater")

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  dd
V = 4154.5, p-value = 0.001487
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location is greater than 0
```

In this example, there is no need to look at results from
a sign test, but we show the results for comparison with
the small sample. [If we believe the the Wilcoxon signed-rank test is correct, it would be "P-hacking" to use
the P-value from the sign test just because it happens
to be smaller for the dataset used here.]

```
binom.test(75, 112, alt="greater")

        Exact binomial test

data:  75 and 112
number of successes = 75, number of trials = 112, 
 p-value = 0.0002105
alternative hypothesis: 
 true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5892731 1.0000000
sample estimates:
 probability of success 
              0.6696429 

1 - pbinom(74, 112, 0.5)
[1] 0.000210484
```

---

*Notes:* (1) P-values for two-sided alternatives will be twice as large as the P-values for the one-sided alternatives shown in the examples above.)

(2) It is important to decide ahead of time (before taking and seeing data) what test will be used
for analysis of an experiment. If Wilcoxon signed-rank
tests are contemplated, it is important to know whether
the sample size is such that unequivocal P-values will
be available.

(3) There are philosophical difficulties doing
'arithmetic' on inherently categorical Likert scores.

These are especially problematic when one undertakes
to do t tests on Likert data (Likert scores are not
even truly numerical, let alone approximately normal).
Some social and biological scientists make arguments
in defense of pretending Likert scores or sums of them
can be treated as normal, but those arguments are controversial. [Data vectors `d` and `dd` are clearly
not normal.]

Taking differences of Likert scores
for paired Wilcoxon tests seems to be somewhat less
controversial, but there is still a latent assumption
that the difference between Likert 1 and 2 is the
'same' as the difference between Likert 4 and 5. (Or that the difference between Likert 3 and 5 is 'twice as large' as the difference between 4 and 5, and so on.)

Using sign tests for differences in Likert scores
is perhaps less controversial because the issue can be viewed as
whether the difference is positive or negative, not
the magnitude of the difference.